# Why does my application keeps switching to a different monitor when it regains focus?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, multiple-monitors, window-focus

I'm working in a dual-monitor setup, with FireFox maximized to one monitor.

When I minimize or close Firefox, or switch to a different application that completely hides Firefox, when I *return* to FireFox, it is now on the other monitor.

NB: I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this forum post,](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=847096&#r13) (at Whirlpool.net, of all places!) FireFox only remembers the current location **when it is not maximized**:

Firefox only remember[s] which monitor they are on if you close Firefox while it is not maximised.

So procedure to get firefox to open maximised on the monitor of your choice in dual monitor setup:

1. Un-maximise Firefox window
2. Position un-maximised window on monitor of you choice
3. Close Firefox window
4. Reopen Firefox window
5. Maximise Firefox window
6. Close Firefox window

Now Firefox will open maximised on the screen you chose.

---

Following these steps resolved my long-standing weird issue.

More technical information on this issue can be found at this blog post on [Multi-Monitor Programming Pitfalls](http://blog.gurock.com/articles/multi-monitor-programming-pitfalls/) which reveals **it is not solely a FireFox issue.**

Comment: This can happen to other applications as well. I recall it on Internet Explorer 6 too.

Comment: The blog-post suggests it's a bug that affects any application that doesn't store size and position when maximized.

Comment: Perhaps I should have read the blog post before commenting, then :-).