# Fullscreen application minimizing when focus shifts to it from second monitor. Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have application X running full screen on my secondary monitor without focus. If I switch to this application from an application on my primary monitor by clicking, application X will minimize itself. The oddest thing is that to return the application to normal, I have to click the taskbar icon twice to get it to return. This seems to happen the most after I minimize and return the application to the second monitor.

---

Machine Information

Secondary Monitor: Acer S231HL(Analog)

Primary Monitor:   Acer GN256HL

Graphics Card: Nvidia GTX 660 TI

---

Other Possibly Useful Information

I run Emerge Desktop 6.2.0.1328

I have looked at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/363152/why-does-my-application-keeps-switching-to-a-different-monitor-when-it-regains-f)
Not sure if it is pertinent/the solution or not.